# bootstrap datepicker focusout when clicking on the calendar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using this [Bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in my ASP.NET project. I set a function for every input that will check its value on the 'focusout' event. If the input's value is empty, the input will be marked red like this:
[image]

But the issue is, looks like the bootstrap datepicker will trigger its input's focusout event whenever user clicks on the calendar. Which means, if the datepicker's input is empty before user chooses the date, after user clicks on any date on the calendar, the input will still be marked red.

[image]

[image]

any ideas?
I was planning to change the focusout behavior for the datepicker's input. The new function will check if the calendar is on the screen first, if true, then do nothing, else check the input's value. The logic should work but sadly I don't know how to check if the calendar is on or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. It's every easy, just use the 'hide' event rather than the focusout event for the datepickers.